# Access append query keeps saying 0 rows to append despite data being in all of the tables or queries

Tags: sql, ms-access

I haven't messed with access in over 15 years so I'm a bit off on some of minutia that goes with it.  We recently upgraded from office 2007 to 365 and after going to the new version this query stopped working.  As stated, there is data in the other queries and tables that this is pulling from but it's coming back with 0 to update.

it's not pretty (I didn't write this, just had it dumped in my lap) and worked properly before the upgrade.

```
INSERT INTO Handle_Temp ( Location, Host, [Date], Type, Win, Place, Show, Quinella, DailyDouble, Perfecta, Pick3, Pick9, Superfecta, Trifecta, Breakage, MinusPool, SComm, GComm, EComm, Surcharge, ArlSurcharge, StraightComm, GimComm, ExComm, Payout, NetPool )
SELECT DISTINCTROW ToteLocation.Location, ToteHost.Host, qry_handle_Combined.Date, Tracktype.Type, qry_handle_Combined.Win, qry_handle_Combined.Place, qry_handle_Combined.Show, qry_handle_Combined.Quinella, qry_handle_Combined.DailyDouble, qry_handle_Combined.Perfecta, qry_handle_Combined.Pick3, 0 AS Pick9, qry_handle_Combined.Superfecta, qry_handle_Combined.Trifecta, [qry_breakage_combined]![Breakage] AS Break, qry_minuspool_combined.MinusPool, [qry_commission_combined]![StraightComm]-(([qry_handle_Combined]![Win]+[qry_handle_Combined]![Place]+[qry_handle_Combined]![Show]+[qry_handle_Combined]![Quinella]+[qry_handle_Combined]![DailyDouble]+[qry_handle_Combined]![Perfecta]+[qry_handle_Combined]![Pick3]+[qry_handle_Combined]![Superfecta]+[qry_handle_Combined]![Trifecta])*[StateTaxRate]![Rate]) AS SComm, [qry_commission_combined]![GimComm] AS GComm, [qry_commission_combined]![ExComm] AS EComm, [qry_surcharge_combined]![Surcharge] AS ILSUR, qry_surchbreak.DimeBreak, qry_commission_combined.StraightComm, qry_commission_combined.GimComm, qry_commission_combined.ExComm, qry_payout_combined.SumOfSumOfPayout, qry_netpool_combined.SumOfSumOfNetPool
FROM StateTaxRate INNER JOIN ((qry_payout_combined INNER JOIN (qry_netpool_combined INNER JOIN ((qry_commission_combined INNER JOIN (ToteHost RIGHT JOIN (ToteLocation RIGHT JOIN (qry_surcharge_combined INNER JOIN (qry_minuspool_combined INNER JOIN (qry_breakage_combined INNER JOIN qry_handle_Combined ON (qry_breakage_combined.Meet = qry_handle_Combined.Meet) AND (qry_breakage_combined.Date = qry_handle_Combined.Date) AND (qry_breakage_combined.Program = qry_handle_Combined.Program) AND (qry_breakage_combined.Source = qry_handle_Combined.Source) AND (qry_breakage_combined.Community = qry_handle_Combined.Community)) ON (qry_minuspool_combined.Meet = qry_handle_Combined.Meet) AND (qry_minuspool_combined.Date = qry_handle_Combined.Date) AND (qry_minuspool_combined.Program = qry_handle_Combined.Program) AND (qry_minuspool_combined.Source = qry_handle_Combined.Source) AND (qry_minuspool_combined.Community = qry_handle_Combined.Community)) ON (qry_surcharge_combined.Meet = qry_handle_Combined.Meet) AND (qry_surcharge_combined.Date = qry_handle_Combined.Date) AND (qry_surcharge_combined.Program = qry_handle_Combined.Program) AND (qry_surcharge_combined.Source = qry_handle_Combined.Source) AND (qry_surcharge_combined.Community = qry_handle_Combined.Community)) ON ToteLocation.Source = qry_handle_Combined.Source) ON ToteHost.Program = qry_handle_Combined.Program) ON (qry_commission_combined.Meet = qry_handle_Combined.Meet) AND (qry_commission_combined.Date = qry_handle_Combined.Date) AND (qry_commission_combined.Program = qry_handle_Combined.Program) AND (qry_commission_combined.Source = qry_handle_Combined.Source) AND (qry_commission_combined.Community = qry_handle_Combined.Community)) LEFT JOIN Tracktype ON (qry_handle_Combined.Meet = Tracktype.Meet) AND (qry_handle_Combined.Program = Tracktype.Program)) ON (qry_netpool_combined.Meet = qry_handle_Combined.Meet) AND (qry_netpool_combined.Date = qry_handle_Combined.Date) AND (qry_netpool_combined.Program = qry_handle_Combined.Program) AND (qry_netpool_combined.Source = qry_handle_Combined.Source) AND (qry_netpool_combined.Community = qry_handle_Combined.Community)) ON (qry_payout_combined.Meet = qry_handle_Combined.Meet) AND (qry_payout_combined.Date = qry_handle_Combined.Date) AND (qry_payout_combined.Program = qry_handle_Combined.Program) AND (qry_payout_combined.Source = qry_handle_Combined.Source) AND (qry_payout_combined.Community = qry_handle_Combined.Community)) INNER JOIN qry_surchbreak ON (qry_surchbreak.Meet = qry_handle_Combined.Meet) AND (qry_handle_Combined.Date = qry_surchbreak.Date) AND (qry_handle_Combined.Program = qry_surchbreak.Program) AND (qry_handle_Combined.Source = qry_surchbreak.Source) AND (qry_handle_Combined.Community = qry_surchbreak.Community)) ON StateTaxRate.SourceID = qry_handle_Combined.Source
WHERE (((qry_handle_Combined.Date) Between [StateTaxRate]![BDate] And [StateTaxRate]![EDate]) AND ((qry_handle_Combined.Source)="ATB" Or (qry_handle_Combined.Source)="CBD" Or (qry_handle_Combined.Source)="EFF" Or (qry_handle_Combined.Source)="FAR" Or (qry_handle_Combined.Source)="GVL" Or (qry_handle_Combined.Source)="QUY" Or (qry_handle_Combined.Source)="SPF" Or (qry_handle_Combined.Source)="AI" Or (qry_handle_Combined.Source)="WK" Or (qry_handle_Combined.Source)="QC" Or (qry_handle_Combined.Source)="RF" Or (qry_handle_Combined.Source)="MB" Or (qry_handle_Combined.Source)="SAU" Or (qry_handle_Combined.Source)="EG" Or (qry_handle_Combined.Source)="MC" Or (qry_handle_Combined.Source)="SB" Or (qry_handle_Combined.Source)="LP" Or (qry_handle_Combined.Source)="HW" Or (qry_handle_Combined.Source)="HK" Or (qry_handle_Combined.Source)="SD" Or (qry_handle_Combined.Source)="VP"));
```

Comment: So if you remove the INSERT INTO .... bit of the query, and just run everything from the first SELECT onwards, as a query, you definitely get rows returned?

Comment: @craig no, I'm still getting nothing returned.

Comment: Well, then, you don't have the complete set of data to satisfy the query.  You do have a number of INNER JOINs in the query, so all it takes is for one of those joined tables to not have the related row, and you'll then get no results (regardless of how complete the data is in other tables).  In this sort of instance, I usually first change INNER JOINs to LEFT JOINs, and then I whittle down the "WHERE" criteria to try and identify where there's a missing record (or records).

Answer (score 0):

So there is no data that matches given your comment. Obviously, the query is complicated with many joins and a long where clause. It is looking for qry_handle_Combined.Date Between BDate and EDate. I would try widening those dates with BDate being very early and EDate being very late.

You are probably going to have to copy the query and start simplifying it. What happens if you remove the entire where clause or just the qry_handle_Combined.Source = "XXX" portions and keeping the dates?

If that doesn't work, you may need to remove some of the joins or start re-building it from scratch.